# Don't know how to build task 'environment' When i deploy my app to vps in Capistrano task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I deployed my app to vps with capistrano.
Everything works fine but only :environment task.

This is my code

```
namespace :deploy do

desc 'Clear memcache'
  task clear_memcache: :environment do
    on roles(:app) , in: :sequence, wait: 2 do
      ::Rails.cache.clear
      CACHE.flush
    end
  end

    after  :finishing,    :clear_memcache

end
```

But i always got this error.

```
#<RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'environment' (see --tasks)>
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing two concepts. A rake task and a capistrano task. Rake tasks do use the `:environment` subtask, whereas the capistrano ones don't. Capistrano tasks cannot (AFAIK) directly call ruby code in the context of the rails application on the server, this is what rake tasks do.

What you actually probably want is to define **both a rake task** to clear the cache **and a capistrano task** that will call the rake task on the deployment server.

Try these:

The rake task to clear the cache:

```
# put this in Rakefile or any other rake file under lib/tasks
desc 'Clear memcache'
task clear_memcache: :environment do
  ::Rails.cache.clear
  CACHE.flush
end
```

The capistrano task to call the rake on the server:

```
# config/deploy/production.rb
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Clear memcache'
  task :clear_memcache do
    on roles(:app) , in: :sequence, wait: 2 do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute 'rake', 'clear_memcache'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after  :finishing, :clear_memcache    
end
```

Comment: what is the file name for the file inside lib/tasks ?

Comment: You can name it anything you like, with a `.rake` extension, for example `memcache.rake` is OK.

Comment: i made this file clear_memcache.rake in side lib/tasks added your code but still got untimeError: Don't know how to build task 'environment'

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, when copy-pasting the tasks, I accidently left the `:environment` in the capistrano task too. Please see the updated capistrano task in my answer.